# On a hyperbola, find the point on the hyperbola that is distanced 3 times further from one asymptote than the other.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The equation of the hyperbola is $\ \frac{x^2}{64} - \frac{y^2}{36}=1$

So that means I have the asymptote formulas as well since I can get a and b easily out of the hyperbola equation. I then use the formula for distance, made a ratio for one to be 3 times bigger than the other and I get that the points cordinates are ratioed $\ 12x = -15y $.

I am stuck after that. Any tips?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, if the point in question has to be ON the hyperbola, then you could intersect the hyperbola with $12x=-15y$. Now you have a system of 2 equations. Eliminating one variable through substitution results in a quadratic equation. (Maybe there is more than one point that would work)

Comment: Yes, it has to be on the hyperbola. @imranfat

Comment: Rewrite $\frac{x^2}{64}$ as $\frac{144x^2}{9216}$ amd now replace $144x^2$ by $225y^2$. You get a quadratic equation with annoying fractions.

Comment: I dont quite get what you are telling me ? @imranfat

Comment: He’s telling you that you now have a system of two equations that describe the intersection of the hyperbola with a line. Solve the system.

Comment: I made the assumption that your work is correct. When you graph your hyperbola and $12x=-15y$, you will see that they don't intersect. So something isn't quite right here.

Comment: Revise your work: given asymptotes, you should find FOUR lines whose points have distances from them in the ratio $1:3$. Only two of these, however, intersect the hyperbola.